# Tkinter - Choose what labels to display

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a workout generator. I want to randomize what exercises it displays each time on the screen. However, using the `random.sample` function does not seem to work, and instead all of the labels are displayed. This or `None` is displayed. Upon research I haven't found any similar functionality with the same problem I have.

```
def Strength():
    class Strength:
        def __init__(self, root):
            self.root = root
            self.root.title = ("Strength")
            self.root.geometry("600x600")

            PowerFrame = self.root

            def Arms():
                Preacher_Curls = Label(PowerFrame, text="Preacher Curls")
                Preacher_Curls.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)


                Cable_Curls = Label(PowerFrame, text="Cable Curls")
                Cable_Curls.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)


                Tricep_Dips = Label(PowerFrame, text="Tricep Dips")
                Tricep_Dips.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)

                Exercises = (Preacher_Curls, Cable_Curls, Tricep_Dips)
                Choice = random.sample(Exercises, 2)
                #Text = Label(PowerFrame,text=Choice)
                #Text.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    application = Strength(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. Right now your code doesn't make much sense (and errors will occur when running it) since there is both a function *and* a class named `Strength`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, an **interactive** community. Interact with the community so they can tell if the question has been answered. If an answer meets your needs accept the answer. If the question has not been answered add comments. Possibly clarify your question. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provides information to help you succeed. Creating an MRE has two benefits. You may solve the problem while creating the MRE. If, not then posting the MRE will help others provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest removing `def Strength():` so that `Strength()` creates a class instance.

`def Arms():` to `def Arms(self):` and dedented to line up with `def __init__` inside class.

Then can call `self.Arms()` inside class or `application.Arms()` outside class if wanted. Need to see how `Arms()` is called to see how you get the results you describe with this code.